# How to split the list with '-' as delimiter, at the same time string contains '-'?

Tags: python, split

I want to split the string to get the email by `-` as a delimiter, but both the email and the name contains `-`, how can I exclude `-` in email and name?

Below is the sample dataframe, the first row is good; the second row, `mrs.jay-zee` is the name, `jz@gmail.com` is the email; the third row, `mary-alice` is the name, `ma-4ever@outlook.com` is the email.

```
contact=['mr.wan-wan@yahoo.com-3918880000','mrs.jay-zee-jz@gmail.com-3800888899','mary-alice-ma-4ever@outlook.com-3600669966']
df=pd.DataFrame(contact,columns=['contacts'])
```

if I use the following lambda function, I get the wrong answer. What's the appropriate way to achieve my goal?

```
df['contacts'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[1])
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `rsplit`, or better `rpartition`

Comment: What's the rule you need to apply? For example, if the value is "mrs.jay-zee-jz@gmail.com", how do you know it's "jz@gmail.com" and not "zee-jz@gmail.com"? Both are valid email addresses, and presumably both "mrs.jay" and "mrs.jay-zee" are valid names. It seems like you have data that could be impossible to parse correctly.

Comment: Hello, There is no rule. I know it is jz@gmail.com, just because I know. That's my problem, I don't have a very good way to parse the data... this is frustrating.

Comment: Please elaborate on rsplit and rpartition. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of splitting & trying to merge back, why not replace the terminal `-` & digits with `''`

```
df.contacts.str.replace('-\d+$', '')
outputs:
0               mr.wan-wan@yahoo.com
1           mrs.jay-zee-jz@gmail.com
2    mary-alice-ma-4ever@outlook.com
```

unfortunately, as there can be `-` in both the email, and the name, it isn't possible to determine where the name ends, and where the email begins, simply by looking at the string.

I mean, it is conceivable that a person is named `mary alice ma` having the email `4ever@outlook.com` instead of `mary alice` having the email `ma-4ever@outlook.com`

your best bet is to treat contacts with 2 or more `-` characters before the `@` manually. But for records with only 1 `-`, it can safely be inferred that the `-` separates the name from the email address, and names / emails can be extracted for these records only using:

```
df['name_email'] = df.contacts.str.replace('-\d+$', '')
df['ambiguous'] = df.name_email.apply(lambda x: len(re.findall('-', x)) > 1)
df[['name', 'email']] = df.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series([None, None]) if x.ambiguous else pd.Series(x.name_email.split('-')), 
    axis=1
)
```

Then, for the resulting data frame, write more specific code to treat the cases with multiple `-`.

Comment: Thank you. You are right about it is impossible to determine the name and email. I could determine the sample because I know the email and the name. It is a good thinking to separate with space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to do this:

```
import re

VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = '\w+[-\w]+@\w+[\.\w]+'
emailaddr = lambda x: re.compile(VALID_EMAIL_REGEX).search(x).group(0)

df['contacts'].apply(emailaddr)
```

Will work on any form of combination of `-` and `[a-zA-Z]` to the left of the `@` and only any combination of `.` and `[a-zA-Z]` to the left of a `-` but to the right of the `@`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been studying Regex for the past 30 mins:)

Comment: this is what I got, this is not exactly what I am looking for.
0                  wan-wan@yahoo.com
1              jay-zee-j-z@gmail.com
2    mary-alice-ma-4ever@outlook.com